# How can I display the Charts dialog in Word, with VBA, for someone to select from?

Tags: vba, charts, ms-word

I have built a custom tab in Word 2007, using CustomUI editor for a specific pitch template in Word, and need to set up a number of buttons to do custom things for the users. All done, except one.

The client has asked if I could add a charts button, but to show the chart's templates list directly, as these are the ones they should be using. I have reviewed the 'show dialog' list on Microsoft's site, but nothing seems to be able to do this. I don't even seem to be able to show the main charts list, which would be something. Recording the action only stores the specific chart ID and the insertion of a chosen chart, which is not really what I am after.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar to one i have posted recently and i have discovered a workaround that could work for you as well.

In office 2007, that dialog can be invoked by pressing `ALT+B+C`, so the macro can replicate that behaviour:

```
ThisDocument.Application.Activate
VBA.SendKeys "%bc", True
```

Maybe this is not the best approach, but the Ribbon hierarchy is too complicated for me.